# ES6 while destructuring parameters can I access the containing object?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Use case: I would like to use destructuring to access individual field of the object but I would also like to have access to the object as a whole.

I know I can do this:

```js
function auth(cred) {
   const {user, pwd} = cred;
    // rest of the code
}
```

But is there a ES6 correct way of doing this?
Perhaps something akin Clojure's :as - for example,

```
(let [[item1 :as all] names] )
```

```js
function auth({ user, pwd :as all}) {
  // i can access user and pwd but can i access whole containing object
  }
```

Comment: `function auth({user, pwd}) {`

Comment: Your first snippet is totally fine and idiomatic ES6. Just use that.